# How do I generate a random number within a non-contiguous range using Ruby?

Tags: ruby

For example suppose I have the following ranges

5031..5032  6248..6249

How do I generate a random number within these two ranges?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple way:

```
(r1.to_a + r2.to_a).choice
```

A faster and much more memory-efficient general solution would involve computing the total range size, generating a random number, and then normalizing the number to the range that it falls in.

Update: Ok, got it. This solution works with an arbitrary number of Ranges and does *not* generate giant arrays or iterate through the Ranges themselves. (It iterates twice over an array of *Ranges*, not arrays of Range elements.)

```
def rangerand *r
  r.inject(rand(
      r.inject(0) do |accum, rng|
        accum + rng.last - rng.first + 1
      end
    )) do |accum, rng|
      rngsize = rng.last - rng.first + 1
      return rng.first + accum if accum < rngsize
      accum - rngsize
    end
  # raise 'this "cannot happen"'
end

puts rangerand 1..3, 999..1001, 10_200..10_205
```

Heh, I've never used two `#inject`s in the same expression before.

Comment: This looks like it wishes for some Haskell-style function composition or F#-style function pipelining operators built into Ruby :-)

Comment: If the value of the first inject is calculated in a separate line it is more clear. And probably Integer(rand * N) -> rand(N).

Comment: @tokland, OK, #rand API use improved, thanks. I can't seem to make my fingers break up the single expression, though. :-)

Comment: You should *not* use `choice`. It is named `sample` in all version above 1.8.7. Also, note that your algorithm won't work properly for exclusive ranges (e.g. 1...42)

Comment: That's not clear. In 1.8.7 and below, `#choice` *does not work*. In either version, you need to monkey-patch Range or use a compatibility gem, and in that case either will work. Not every SO answer gets into that level of detail.  It's not strictly true that "my algorithm" doesn't work for exclusive ranges. My first "algorithm" *does*, and the second one can be made to work by adding a bit of complexity, just subtract (rng.exclude_end? ? 1:0) from each use of rng.last.

Answer (score 4):

For arbitrary number of ranges

1. Count number of possible values as `total`.
2. Generate random number `rnd` between `0` and `total - 1`.
3. Iterate through list of ranges, subtracting range size from `rnd` until possible (until `rnd` is non-negative).
4. When can't subtract more, just get `rnd`-th number in the current range.

Comment: @Ryan Why? You can implement generic algorithm in three minutes. It's not code-gold, after all.

Comment: +1 Actually this seems to be the best answer as it doesn't expand ranges into arrays.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to implement this and see which one is better. One more question, isn't iteration expensive?

Comment: @JayX Let me know if you have problem with implementation. As for better, if total size of all ranges is under 100, I would go with it `to_a`. It won't cost too much.

Comment: I would say it took me a bit more than three minutes, but I'm glad I did it and found the two-inject solution. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I wrote this code and looking now at Nikita's answer I think it's more or less his idea (I use `r.end`/`r.begin` because Ruby ranges have no pre-calculated length attribute)

```
ranges = [1..10, 21..40, 81..120]

counts = ranges.map { |r| r.end - r.begin + (r.exclude_end? ? 0 : 1) }
random = rand(counts.inject(&:+))    
idx, remainder = counts.inject([0, random]) do |(idx, remainder), count|
  if remainder < count
    [idx, remainder] # break here if you care more for efficiency than for functional purity
  else
    [idx+1, remainder - count]
  end
end
p ranges[idx].begin + remainder
```

Of course if I had ranges of *reasonable* length, I'd simply use the other solutions already discussed.

Answer (score 1):

Add the ranges to an array and flatten it to get a series of numbers, then call `rand` to find a particular element of this array.

```
range_1 = 1..10
range_2 = 2..30

range_array = [range_1.to_a, range_2.to_a].flatten
range_array[rand(range_array.length)]
```

Comment: A nicer expression is (r1.to_a + r2.to_a).choice

Comment: @DigitalRoss Array#choice is gone in 1.9.2 . It's replaced by Array#sample

Comment: To all the people saying "it won't work with big ranges", the question originally stated two very small ranges. I answered to suit the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with:

```
require 'benchmark'

class RangeRandom
  def initialize(ranges=[])

    # sanity checks need to go here for things like:
    #   backward/inverted ranges: (0..-1)
    #   range overlaps: (0..2 & 1..3)
    #     could combine ranges, or raise an exception
    #
    # Restrict to ranges that pass ".inclusive?"?

    # the end value is informative only
    @prepped_ranges = ranges.map{ |r| [ r.begin, r.end - r.begin, r.end ] }
  end

  def rand
    range = @prepped_ranges[ Kernel::rand( @prepped_ranges.size ) ]
    range[0] + Kernel::rand( range[1] )
  end
end
```

Some tests:

```
range_random = RangeRandom.new([0..10, 90..100])
5.times do
  puts range_random.rand
end
puts

# >> 94
# >> 97
# >> 92
# >> 92
# >> 8

n = 500_000
Benchmark.bm(7) do |x|
  x.report('rand1:') { n.times do ; r = RangeRandom.new([ 0..1             ]); r.rand; end }
  x.report('rand2:') { n.times do ; r = RangeRandom.new([ 0..1_000_000     ]); r.rand; end }
  x.report('rand3:') { n.times do ; r = RangeRandom.new([ 0..1_000_000_000 ]); r.rand; end }

  x.report('rand4:') { n.times do ; r = RangeRandom.new([ 0..1 ]); r.rand; end }
  x.report('rand5:') { n.times do ; r = RangeRandom.new([ 0..1, 2..3, 4..5, 6..7 ]); r.rand; end }

  x.report('rand6:') { r = RangeRandom.new([ 0..1             ]) ; n.times do ; r.rand; end }
  x.report('rand7:') { r = RangeRandom.new([ 0..1_000_000_000 ]) ; n.times do ; r.rand; end }
end
```

Overall run times for 500,000 iterations:

```
# >>              user     system      total        real
# >> rand1:   2.220000   0.000000   2.220000 (  2.224894)
# >> rand2:   2.250000   0.010000   2.260000 (  2.254730)
# >> rand3:   2.250000   0.000000   2.250000 (  2.247406)
```

Times for initializing multiple ranges for 500,000 iterations:

```
# >> rand4:   2.220000   0.000000   2.220000 (  2.222983)
# >> rand5:   4.340000   0.000000   4.340000 (  4.337312)
```

Times for a single initialization, then a small range vs. big range for 500,000 iterations:

```
# >> rand6:   0.560000   0.000000   0.560000 (  0.559673)
# >> rand7:   0.580000   0.000000   0.580000 (  0.584331)
```

Times increase a little when using big ranges but that might be variations due to system activity. Initializing multiple ranges in the array has a greater effect which is what I expected.

Answer (score 0):

For wide ranges **range.to_a** is not a very good solution. You can create unnecessarily many big arrays. Fastest solution can look like this:

```
ruby-1.9.2-head > from, to = 1, 50000000
 => [1, 50000000] 
ruby-1.9.2-head > from + rand(to-from+1) 
 => 20698596 
ruby-1.9.2-head > from + rand(to-from+1) 
 => 15143263 
ruby-1.9.2-head > from + rand(to-from+1) 
 => 18469491
```

Similar solution for Ranges is however almost as slow as **range.to_a**:

```
ruby-1.9.2-head > range1 = 1..5000000
 => 50..50000 
ruby-1.9.2-head > range1.begin + rand(range1.count)   # TAKES ABOUT 1 SECOND!
 => 1788170
```

Comment: Oops, then my answer it's not so efficient after all, I was confident that range.count needed no time to be calculated! we'll have to check how Ruby does it, apparently it's travelling the whole range. Anyway, for (x..y) ranges we can assume count = y - x + 1

Comment: Yup. It's better to calculate it by hand. Range#count comes from Enumerable, so to get the range size, it has to unwind whole collection first:/